# OpenProcess iexplore.exe on other user accounts fails with Access Denied

Tags: c++, winapi, openprocess

I'm working on enumerating instances of iexplore.exe across all users. I'm able to get a list of the matching processes on the machine, but to identify the user, I need to use OpenProcess. This works on my own instances, but even with Run as Administrator and EnableDebugPriv, I'm still getting the access denied message. Am I missing something? Is iexplore.exe somehow protected?

Here's what I'm using for the debug priv:

```
void EnableDebugPriv()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    if (!::LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid))
    {
        wprintf(_T("ERROR %u\n"),GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hToken); 
        return;
    }

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!::AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tkp, sizeof(tkp), NULL, NULL))
    {
        wprintf(_T("ERROR %u\n"),GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hToken); 
        return;
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    wprintf(_T("Should have worked"));
}
```

No errors occur when I run this. The ACCESS DENIED error occurs when I run

```
hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_TERMINATE , FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID );
```

For processes that don't belong to me. The "other" users are Standard and Guest accounts created on this machine in a normal way from Control Panel. Any ideas would be much appreciated. I'm stuck! Ultimately I want to offer the user the ability to shut down the app, but even with just PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION it fails. I still need to check if this is the problem with other applications besides IE.

**Update** I ultimately got this to work. The error was in OpenProcessToken instead. And I needed a different privilege than I asked for.

Comment: Even if you managed to get this to work, what do you intend to do with the process handle?

Comment: Hi, I got this to work. I needed it to locate the user of the process.

Comment: If all you want is to identify the user that owns the process, then you don't need to open the process at all. Use `WTSEnumerateProcesses`. It returns you all the processes, their names, and their owners - all at one shot.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that. That's fantastic.

Comment: Wait, apparently WTSEnumerateProcesses is limited in XP.

Comment: @tofutim What privilege did you ask for in OpenProcessInformation?

Comment: @tofutim, well the real question in here is what was the incorrect privilege and what was the problem with "OpenProcessToken"? You see, StakOverflow is a place to share the information as well as asking for help. And I am asking for help now :|

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista and later, IE runs in Protected Mode as a Low-Integrity process.  [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880.aspx), non-protected processes have restricted access to protected processes, including `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` and `PROCESS_VM_READ` rights.